# Android ListView Item animates after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

**My Problem:**
An item in my ListView animates after I begin scrolling. It is not the last item and animation should be finished. After I have scrolled once the problem is gone, It only happens once and on a single item in the list.

How can I stop that single item from animating after I begin to scroll the ListView?

**I want** the animation to run only once when an item is added to the adapter.

I have a list adapter in which I am animating items as they are added to a list. I am using a declared animator to slide in the items from the left in the getView() method of my adapter. Here is my getView() method where the animation is applied.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
String listItemText = mList.get(position);
ViewHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.mListItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_title);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_in_left);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.mListItemText.setText(listItemText);

return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView mListItemText;

}
```

Comment: You should use `ViewPropertyAnimator` instead. Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convertView is null the first time that the list try to build a row.
so your animation start only the first time and in the first item.

What you want is to animate an item if, for example, a flag is set to true.

An example:

To check if an item is new i'll do in this way:

```
public void initList() {
    /* Change your mList to get Bundle instead of String */
    mList = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
}

/* When you add an item you will put a bundle with your string and a flag that tell the item is new */
public void addItem(String item) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("string", item);
    bundle.putBoolean("new", true);
    mList.add(bundle);
}
```

Now check if the object is new:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
    Bundle item = mList.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mListItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_title);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mListItemText.setText(item.getString("string"));

    if(item.getBoolean("new") == true) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        item.setBoolean("new", false);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This has improved the situation a lot. Now when I scroll all of the items that were previously off the screen animate. It looks a lot better than just 1 random item animating. Is there a way to tell items off the screen to not animate as they become visible?

Comment: i'm updating the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update & answer. I really like the bundle solution and appreciate the help. Unfortunately items that are off screen when added still animate only after they are scrolled onto the screen however I think that is a separate problem/question from what I have asked and animating on scroll is fine for my project.